# Matching 2 audio files

Tags: audio, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, cross-correlation, java

I'm doing research on how we can do matching between 2 audio files using Android to see if they have the same content or not. After doing lots of research, I have concluded that I must do 2 main things:

1. FFT
2. Correlation

Am I on the right track?

Comment: How are the two files similar?  Are they identical enough where one can do a bitwise compare?

Comment: in similar i mean they have the same words and phrases ... you know? like to see if 2 people said the same thing. @hotpaw2

Comment: If you application is speech, you should look, specifically, into the extensive speech recognition literature. This is not my specialty, but my understanding is that FFT and correlation are generally considered too CPU-intensive to be useful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition#Algorithms

Comment: I tried doing speech recognition using google service ,,, but i was not accurate! (in my language) @Bjorn Roche  sooo im trying to use the DSP approach. so you think FFT wont work?

Comment: Correlation will identify two waveforms with similar shape. It won't help you find similar words. It is usually implemented using fft for speed but doesn't have to be

Comment: Possibly the same as this question? http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9860/is-possible-to-compare-to-audio-samples-with-cross-correlation

Comment: After experimenting ,,, i have concluded that i am on the right track. thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on which application you have...the algorithms for speech recognition are different from speech indentification for example. Based on what you need, just look for an open source library for Java. Getting into the theory is definitely desired but as a first step you can just look for a software block that has inputs/outputs, later you can drill into it.

Here is some info on speech recog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018418/open-source-simple-speech-recognition-in-c-in-windows

Comment: my application is going to be an app which does matching between 2 audio files. And i already started! and i have an app which records 2 voices and im working on the FFT right now. i just need someone to assure me that what im doing is correct,,, because some people tell me im lost! :O

Comment: but what are you trying to do? can you describe the application?

Answer (score 0):

cross spectral match 2 audio wav[image]

https://github.com/llpassarelli/cross_spec_lab